# JSON_EXTRACT for a range of dates (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I read multiple times the MYSQL guide for JSON (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

But I still don't find a way to query a range of dates.

I have the following stored JSON:

```
{"2014/12/10": [22.12323, 1212312.36], "2014/12/11": [24.983516, 59239590.36], "2014/12/15": [24.353891, 10350984.54], "2014/12/16": [24.756853, 51752318.09], "2014/12/17": [24.782038, 31848161.91]}
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(contenido, '$."2014/12/11"', '$."2014/12/16"') AS resultado
FROM
    tabla_prueba;
```

I expect the result of:

```
[24.983516, 59239590.36],  [24.353891, 10350984.54],  [24.756853, 51752318.09]
```

But instead, I am getting only the two mentioned values:

```
[24.983516, 59239590.36], [24.756853, 51752318.09]
```

I also tried the key word `to` (for ranges) but with no results. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: JSON_EXTRACT extracts values for specified paths only. None BETWEEN can be applied. I recomment you to parse your JSON to separate values using JSON_TABLE.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 1):

Using [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)
Try:

```
SET @json = '{
  "2014/12/10": [
    22.12323,
    1212312.36
  ],
  "2014/12/11": [
    24.983516,
    59239590.36
  ],
  "2014/12/15": [
    24.353891,
    10350984.54
  ],
  "2014/12/16": [
    24.756853,
    51752318.09
  ],
  "2014/12/17": [
    24.782038,
    31848161.91
  ]
}';

SELECT a.dateStr, json_extract(@json, concat('$."', a.dateStr, '"')) as vals
FROM json_table(json_keys(@json), '$[*]' COLUMNS (dateStr CHAR(10) PATH '$')) a
WHERE a.dateStr BETWEEN '2014/12/11' AND '2014/12/16';
```

Result:

| dateStr | vals |
| --- | --- |
| 2014/12/11 | [24.983516, 59239590.36] |
| 2014/12/15 | [24.353891, 10350984.54] |
| 2014/12/16 | [24.756853, 51752318.09] |